# removing directory and sub directory which is not present in the list

Tags: bash, shell

This is my directory structure

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t
./lisst.txt                  ./SAMN03272855/SRR1734376/SRR1734376_1.fastq.gz
./SAMN03272854/SRR1734375/SRR1734375_2.fastq.gz  ./SAMN07605670/SRR6006890/SRR6006890_2.fastq.gz
./SAMN03272854/SRR1734375/SRR1734375_1.fastq.gz  ./SAMN07605670/SRR6006890/SRR6006890_1.fastq.gz
./SAMN03272855/SRR1734376/SRR1734376_2.fastq.gz
```

So this is a small subset of my **folder/files** where i have around 70.

I have a made a list of files which i want to keep and other i would like to delete.

My list.txt contains `SAMN03272854,SAMN03272855` but I want to remove `SAMN07605670`.

I ran this

```
find . ! -name 'lisst.txt' -type d -exec rm -vrf {} +
```

It removed everything

**QUESTION UPDATE**

In my list it contains the folder i want to keep and the one which are not there are to be removed.

The folders which are to be removed also contains subdirectories and files. I want to remove everything

Comment: `find . -type d -name "SAM*" | grep -vf lisst.txt` Confirm it selects the files to delete. Then change to `find . -type d -name "SAM*" | rm -r $(grep -vf lisst.txt)`

Comment: let me run it and will update you

Comment: it didn;t delete anything

Comment: Confirm it selects the files to delete. (prints the ones you want deleted to the terminal) Then change to `find . -type d -name "SAM*" | rm -r $(grep -vf lisst.txt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command selects each directory in the tree, except a directories of the funny name `lisst.txt`. Once it finds a directory, you do a recursive remove of this directory. No surprise that your files are gone.

You can't use `rm -r` when you want to spare certain files from deletion. This means that you also can't remove a directory, which somewhere below in its subtree has a file you want to keep.

I would run two `find` commands: The first removes all the files, ignoring directories, and second one removes all directories, which are empty (bottom-up). Assuming that SAMN03272854 is indeed a **file** (as you told us in your question), this would be:

```
find . -type f \( ! \( -name SAMN03272854 -o -name SAMN03272855  \) \) -exec rm {}

find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} 2>/dev/null
```

The error redirection in the latter command suppresses messages from `rmdir` for directories which still contain files you want to keep. Of course other messages are also suppressed. I would during debugging run the command without error redirection, to see whether it is basically correct.

Things would get more complicated, if you have files **and** directories to keep, because to keep a directory likely implies to keep all the files below it. In this case, you can use the `-prune` option of `find`, which excludes directories including their subdirectories from being processed. See the *find* man page, which gives examples for this.

Comment: "SAMN03272854" its a directory thats . In my question i made a structure of my directory and sub  directory

Comment: Well, you wrote literally _I have a made a list of files_; that's why I assumed it to be a file. In this case, you will have to use `-prune`, if you want to stick with using `find`. If your requirements get more complicate, you could consider writing your own solution, i.e.first just generate a list of all entries in the directory tree, and then run a program to process this list and decide what to keep and what to remove. Consider using some more flexible language for this (Ruby, Perl, ...) instead of doing it in _bash_.

Comment: "you wrote literally I have a made a list of files;" my bad i biologist i had to get the right words to describe my command line/linux issue i will keep that in mind

Comment: "if you want to stick with using find"  i will prefer anything tht will solve my issue

Comment: If I would program ist, I would probably use _Ruby_. It has something like `find` builtin, and tree traversal is easy, and it has all the data structures which makes life easy. Since you come from biology, you will perhaps be more familiar with _Perl_, which for this purpose would work equally well.

Comment: i will give it a try ..

Comment: Hello Sir Ronald Fischer wow I mean wow i just saw your profile you have lived and worked developed through the evolution of hardware industry